# read a file and put the rows in seprate file due the same value of specefied column in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file named main.txt with 3 columns.
due to column 3 value I want to distinguish rows and put them in separate textfiles.
for example I have

```
12 88 sigma
15 60 beta
12 70 sigma
11 90 alpha
15 44 beta
```

now I want to read file in loop or other way that due to column 3 have files for example named beta.txt which contains:

```
15 60 beta
15 44 beta
```

and other files like sigma.txt and so on...
Im new to bash.I dont have any idea how to start.how can I write this in bash...sorry to not have codes. beforehand thank u for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]] ; do
    read num1 num2 name <<<"$line"
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >>"$name.txt"
done <main.txt
```

Set an empty IFS and use the '-r' option with 'read' to read the line exactly as it is in 'main.txt'.

Test '[[ $line ]]' to handle an unterminated last line in 'main.txt'.

Use 'printf' instead of 'echo' to avoid 'echo' interpreting anything in $line.

If you don't care about preserving spacing in the lines, you could do it with a single 'read':

```
while read num1 num2 name || [[ $num1 ]] ; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$num1" "$num2" "$name" >>"$name.txt"
done <main.txt
```

Note that the output files are not initialized, so the code will append to files created on the first run if it is run more than once.  If that is a problem, one way to fix it is to do a first pass to initialize the output files and a second pass to populate them (as above).  This code could be used to initialize the files:

```
# Initialize output files so new data can safely be added by appending
while read num1 num2 name || [[ $num1 ]] ; do
    echo -n >"$name.txt"
done <main.txt
```

A one-pass solution is also possible.  One way to do it would be to use an associative array (Bash 4+ only) to keep track of which files have been initialized.

Comment: :SINCE I want that each $name.txt file change by new values (for example if I open main.txt with new values the values of $name must be refresh too)I think I should use > ,< instead of >>,<<<.IS it right?

Comment: It would not work to replace `>>` by `>` in the code that populates the output files because each new line that was added would remove the old contents of the file.  I've edited the answer to include details of a two-pass approach to initializing and populating the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a simple awk command:

```
awk '$3=="beta"' alpha.txt > beta.txt

cat beta.txt
15 60 beta
15 44 beta
```

#### [Read more on Awk](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-awk1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{file=$3 ".txt"; print >> file}'
```

or simply

```
awk '{print >> $3 ".txt"}'
```